# systemverilog name conflict between imported packages

Tags: system-verilog

As you can see in code below I have the same parameter name in both package files and the compiler fails due to this ambiguity.  How to fix the SystemVerilog code in the case below?

```
//--------------------------------------
package register1_pkg;

    parameter base_core_regs    = 32'h00003000;

    parameter addr_testreg         = (base_axicore_regs + 32'h0000000C);

endpackage

//--------------------------------------
package register2_pkg;

    parameter base_user_regs    = 32'h00007000;

    parameter addr_testreg         = (base_user_regs + 32'h00000014);

endpackage

//--------------------------------------
module testbench();

timeunit 1ns/10ps; 

import register1_pkg::*;
import register2_pkg::*;

task write;
   input integer addr;
   input integer data;
begin
   $display("write  addr:%x data:%x", addr, data);
end
endtask;

initial begin
    write(addr_testreg, 32'hABCD1234);

    $stop;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete your `import` statements and do this instead:

```
write(register1_pkg::addr_testreg, 32'hABCD1234);
write(register2_pkg::addr_testreg, 32'hABCD1234);
```

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Kpfe

```
//--------------------------------------
package register1_pkg;

    parameter base_core_regs    = 32'h00003000;

    parameter addr_testreg         = (base_core_regs + 32'h0000000C);

endpackage

//--------------------------------------
package register2_pkg;

    parameter base_user_regs    = 32'h00007000;

    parameter addr_testreg         = (base_user_regs + 32'h00000014);

endpackage

//--------------------------------------
module testbench();

timeunit 1ns/10ps; 

task write;
   input integer addr;
   input integer data;
begin
   $display("write  addr:%x data:%x", addr, data);
end
endtask;

initial begin
  write(register1_pkg::addr_testreg, 32'hABCD1234);
  write(register2_pkg::addr_testreg, 32'hABCD1234);
  $stop;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the wildcard import `::*` when you have multiple packages with the same symbol name you want to import. You need to explicitly reference the package symbol to remove the ambiguity.

You can either do an explicit import:

```
import register1_pkg::addr_testreg;
```

or you can explicitly reference the symbol without importing it

```
write(register1_pkg::addr_testreg, 32'hABCD1234);
```